# How to express a literal |, not column separator, in a table?

Tags: org-mode

If I press TAB, inside this table:

```
| foo     | bar |
| |        | @   |
```

I get this:

```
| foo | bar |   |
|     |     | @ |
```

I'm hoping there is a way to 'escape' the `|` in cell 2-1 to show that is it literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to escape `|`: the usual suggestion is to use `\vert` in the text instead of `|` - that does not look like a vertical bar in the emacs buffer of course (it looks like `\vert` :-) ), but when the document is exported (at least to LaTeX/PDF or HTML), you get the vertical bar you want:

```
| a                          | b   |
|----------------------------+-----|
| This has a \vert bar in it | foo |
```

Answer (score 1):

The org-element-parser for table cells (org-version 9.2.3):

```el
(defun org-element-table-cell-parser ()
  "Parse table cell at point.
Return a list whose car is `table-cell' and cdr is a plist
containing `:begin', `:end', `:contents-begin', `:contents-end'
and `:post-blank' keywords."
  (looking-at "[ \t]*\\(.*?\\)[ \t]*\\(?:|\\|$\\)")
  (let* ((begin (match-beginning 0))
     (end (match-end 0))
     (contents-begin (match-beginning 1))
     (contents-end (match-end 1)))
    (list 'table-cell
      (list :begin begin
        :end end
        :contents-begin contents-begin
        :contents-end contents-end
        :post-blank 0))))
```

There is no escape syntax defined for `|`.

Answer (score 1):

If using Emacs's org-mode, you can display a vertical bar in a table field using [the following method](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html#FOOT17):

> To insert a vertical bar into a table field, use `\vert` or, inside a word `abc\vert{}def`.