# disable table mode using either #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE or ‘:’ literal line , but insert latex math block $ ... $

Tags: org-mode, org-export, spacemacs, latex, org-table

I’m trying to typeset a grammar in org markup, but want to use latex symbols in the grammar:

```
a ->  hello
   |  $\neg$ world
   |  universe
```

•  Now, without using `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE` or `:` literal-line prefix, the `|` syntax gets interpreted as a table.

•  The issue is that using either solution **causes the Math latex statement to no longer be recognized.**

Thanks

Comment: What are you planning to do with the grammar? If you are planning to export it to LaTeX, maybe replace `|` by `\vert`? That should preserve the math, although it will admittedly look ugly in the buffer. Unfortunately, there is no way to escape `|` AFAIK.

Comment: @NickD Thanks so much — that’s a great suggestion. I actually am not trying to print pretty PDFs, I just like nice typesetting in buffer view because that’s where I will be studying from mostly.  \vert will work well for PDF time, though!  The reason I have to settle with latex in buffer is ... well, there’s no other way to type math in buffer.. might as well, since I’m typing strange stuff like #contained-in anyways...

Comment: @NickD i’m new to stack exchange, but I don’t see a way to upvote your comment! I guess I don’t have enough rep.  Feel free to post it as the answer and I can accept. best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to escape `|`.

The usual suggestion is to use `\vert` instead of `|`. That will become a vertical bar in exported PDF output, although it will certainly not look pretty in the buffer itself. But it does solve the problem of Org mode interpreting `|` as a table starter and it will not affect use of LaTeX fragments in your file. This is also the suggested workaround when you want to include a vertical bar in the text of an entry in a table - see e.g. [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51312/how-to-express-a-literal-not-column-separator-in-a-table/51314#51314).